# Add element to synchronizedList if not exists

Tags: java, multithreading

I have multithread visit this synchronizedList: downloadingFiles, and I want to add element to this synchronizedList only if this element does not exits in it, does the following double check and synchronized required? and is there a better idea?

```
        if (!downloadingFiles.contains(file.getAbsolutePath())) {
        synchronized(this) {
            if (!downloadingFiles.contains(file.getAbsolutePath())) {
                downloadingFiles.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you considered a synchronized `Set` instead?  Then you can just let the `Set` deal with the issue of duplicates?

Comment: if the list is already synchronized, there is no point for the first check outside the synchronized block.  and if it's not already synchronized, then the first check probably isn't thread safe.

Comment: To add to what @MadProgrammer said, you can use a synchronized LinkedHashSet if insertion order is important.

Comment: @jtahlborn Imagine two threads, both check `List#contains`, the first get through, but before it can the item, the second also gets through (no more lock), you now have an opportunity for both threads to add the same element to the `List`

Comment: @MadProgrammer - did you misread my comment?  i didn't say to remove the contains check, i said to remove the check _outside_ the synchronized block (assuming the list is already synchronized), while maintaining the sync block...

Answer (score 1):

Yes that will work. However, the performance gain by doing the double check locking might not be worth the extra check.

In other words consider leaving off the first if statement unless you really expect the method to be called often by multiple threads.

Also if you are actually using a `Collections.synchronizedList()` you will want to perform your `synchronized(...)` on the list itself since that is what is used internally.

```
synchronized(downloadingFiles) {
    if (!downloadingFiles.contains(file.getAbsolutePath())) {
        downloadingFiles.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
    }
}
```